# Express-validator not executing after multer function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, multer, express-validator

I have a form in my express application for users to enter some text, and also upload 1-3 photos. I'm handling the file uploads to my S3 bucket with multer, and I'm validating the rest of the form with `express-validator`.

This makes my POST route look like:

```
router.post("/list-product", listLimiter, function (req, res) {
  singleUpload(req, res, function (err) {
    // if any multer errors, redirect to form
    if (err) {
      res.redirect(
        "list-product" +
          "?error=Image error, please make sure your file is JPG or PNG"
      );
      return;
    }
    // if no multer errors, validate rest of form
  });
});
```

I'm having issues integrating `express-validator`. I've been stuck on this problem for a few days now, and I think I'm getting close. My code below will catch the multer error, and it will create a new `Product` **if** all the inputs are filled out. So what's happening is my `express-validator` isn't catching the errors here `if (!errors.isEmpty()) { // handle errors` and its just skipping it and going straight to `else { let product = new Product({`. I know this because when I leave the inputs empty, it throws a mongoose error of missing schema paths.

```
let upload = require("../controllers/uploadController");
const singleUpload = upload.single("image");


router.post("/list-product", listLimiter, function (req, res, next) {
  singleUpload(req, res, function (err) {
    // if any multer errors, redirect to form
    if (err) {
      res.redirect(
        "list-product" +
          "?error=Image error, please make sure your file is JPG or PNG"
      );
      return;
    }
    // if no multer errors, validate rest of form

    body("productName")
      .trim()
      .isLength({ min: 1 })
      .withMessage("Please enter the name of your product"),
      body("productPrice")
        .isNumeric()
        .withMessage("Please enter a valid price"),
      body("productCategory")
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 1 })
        .withMessage("Please select the category of your product"),
      body("productDescription")
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 50 })
        .withMessage("Minimum 50 characters")
        .isLength({ max: 500 })
        .withMessage("Maximum 500 characters"),
      body("businessName")
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 1 })
        .withMessage("Please enter the name of your business"),
      body("website")
        .trim()
        .isURL()
        .withMessage("Please enter the URL for your product or business");

    check("*").escape();

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    let errArray = errors.array();

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.render("list", {
        form: req.body,
        errors: errArray,
        msg: "Please check the form for errors",
        option: req.body.productCategory,
      });
      return;
    } else {
      let product = new Product({
        business: req.body.businessName,
        productName: req.body.productName,
        category: req.body.productCategory,
        price: req.body.productPrice,
        description: req.body.productDescription,
        website: req.body.website,
        imageURL:
          "https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + req.imageName,
        imageURL2:
          "https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + req.imageName,
      });
      product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect("/list-product");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I would truly appreciate any help or advice since I have been stuck on this for a few days and am feeling really stupid!..

I will include one final block of code, this is my `express-validator` function that works when I'm just validating the text inputs, so I know this approach does work.. I'm just having a real tough time combining it with the multer function

```
exports.list__post = [
  body("productName")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage("Please enter the name of your product"),
  body("productPrice")
    .isNumeric()
    .withMessage("Please enter a valid price"),
  body("productCategory")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage("Please select the category of your product"),
  body("productDescription")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 50 })
    .withMessage("Minimum 50 characters")
    .isLength({ max: 500 })
    .withMessage("Maximum 500 characters"),
  body("businessName")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage("Please enter the name of your business"),
  body("website")
    .trim()
    .isURL()
    .withMessage("Please enter the URL for your product or business"),

  check("*").escape(),

  (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    let errArray = errors.array();

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      console.log(req.body)
      res.render("list", {
        form: req.body,
        errors: errArray,
        msg: "Please check the form for errors",
        option: req.body.productCategory,
      });
      return;
    } else {
      
      let product = new Product({
        business: req.body.businessName,
        productName: req.body.productName,
        category: req.body.productCategory,
        price: req.body.productPrice,
        description: req.body.productDescription,
        website: req.body.website,
        imageURL: "https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + req.imageName,
        imageURL2:"https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + req.imageName,
      });
      product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect("/list-product");
      });
    }
  },
];
```

Update:

```
// uploadController.js

const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");
const crypto = require("crypto");
require("dotenv").config();

// config aws
aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESSKEYID,
  region: "us-west-2",
});
const s3 = new aws.S3();

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("Invalid format, only JPG and PNG"), false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
  limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 },
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "mybucket",
    acl: "public-read",
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      req.imageName = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
      cb(null, req.imageName);
    },
  }),
});

module.exports = upload;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Fixes:**

- call `singleUpload` in middleware, and here you are uploading single file using `upload.single()`, so you need to remove `multiple` attribute from view file tag, if you want to upload multiple file then use `upload.array('field name', total count of files)`

```
router.post("/list-product", 
  singleUpload,
```

- validate other parameters in middleware
- I have noticed you haven't added `businessName` field in form, so this will return with error, you can add it in form or remove validation from here, and also in schema.

```
  [
    body("productName").trim().isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage("Please enter the name of your product"),
    body("productPrice").isNumeric().withMessage("Please enter a valid price"),
    body("productCategory").trim().isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage("Please select the category of your product"),
    body("productDescription").trim().isLength({ min: 50 }).withMessage("Minimum 50 characters").isLength({ max: 500 }).withMessage("Maximum 500 characters"),
    body("businessName").trim().isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage("Please enter the name of your business"),
    body("website").trim().isURL().withMessage("Please enter the URL for your product or business"),
    check("*").escape()
  ],
```

- middleware callback function, here `req` will provide all body parameters and file object that is uploaded,
- just console `req.body` and using `req.file` will return all details of file that is uploaded in S3, including filename and location, i suggest you to use file name and location from this object, I have console it already,
- handle file extension error using `req.fileTypeInvalid`, that we have passed from fileFitler

```
  function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body, req.file);

    // FILE EXTENSION ERROR
    if (req.fileTypeInvalid) {
        res.redirect("list-product" + "?error=" + req.fileTypeInvalid);
        return;
    }

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        let errArray = errors.array();
        let errorsObj = {}; // access errors indiviually 
        errArray.map((item) => {
            const id = item.param;
            delete item.param;
            errorsObj[id] = item;
        });
        res.render("list", {
            form: req.body,
            errors: errorsObj,
            msg: "Please check the form for errors",
            option: req.body.productCategory,
        });
        return;
    }

    let product = new Product({
        business: req.body.businessName,
        productName: req.body.productName,
        category: req.body.productCategory,
        price: req.body.productPrice,
        description: req.body.productDescription,
        website: req.body.website,
        imageURL: "https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + req.imageName,
    });
    product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect("/list-product");
    });
});
```

---

**Combined Final Version of Request:**

```js
router.post("/list-product", 
  singleUpload, 
  [
    body("productName").trim().isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage("Please enter the name of your product"),
    body("productPrice").isNumeric().withMessage("Please enter a valid price"),
    body("productCategory").trim().isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage("Please select the category of your product"),
    body("productDescription").trim().isLength({ min: 50 }).withMessage("Minimum 50 characters").isLength({ max: 500 }).withMessage("Maximum 500 characters"),
    body("businessName").trim().isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage("Please enter the name of your business"),
    body("website").trim().isURL().withMessage("Please enter the URL for your product or business"),
    check("*").escape()
  ], 
  function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body, req.file);

    // FILE EXTENSION ERROR
    if (req.fileTypeInvalid) {
        res.redirect("list-product" + "?error=Image error, please make sure your file is JPG or PNG");
        return;
    }

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        let errArray = errors.array();
        let errorsObj = {}; // access errors indiviually 
        errArray.map((item) => {
            const id = item.param;
            delete item.param;
            errorsObj[id] = item;
        });
        res.render("list", {
            form: req.body,
            errors: errorsObj,
            msg: "Please check the form for errors",
            option: req.body.productCategory,
        });
        return;
    }

    let product = new Product({
        business: req.body.businessName,
        productName: req.body.productName,
        category: req.body.productCategory,
        price: req.body.productPrice,
        description: req.body.productDescription,
        website: req.body.website,
        imageURL: "https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + req.imageName,
    });
    product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect("/list-product");
    });
});
```

---

One more correction in fileFilter inside `uloadController.js` file, pass error in `req.fileTypeInvalid` and return it, it is handled in request,

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        req.fileTypeInvalid = "Invalid format, only JPG and PNG";
        cb(null, false, req.fileTypeInvalid);
    }
};
```